How to stop instantiating a view before the login session creation is successful in Vaadinflow?
I'm learning Vaadin and springboot, After the login authentication, I am trying to store the username in a static variable so that i can access it from another view and show on top which user is logged in. for example : logged in as : Maya
    public void authenticate(String username, String password) throws AuthException{
        Userr userr = userRepo.getByUsername(username);
        if(userr !=null && userr.checkPassword(password)){
            Notification.show(username + " has logged in");
            VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("username", username);
            VaadinServletService.getCurrentServletRequest().getSession().setAttribute("name", username);
            currentUserName = username;
            createRoutes(userr.getRole());
        }
        else{
            throw new AuthException();
        }
    }

    private void createRoutes(Role role){

        RouteConfiguration configuration = RouteConfiguration
                .forSessionScope();
        configuration.removeRoute("ws");
        configuration.removeRoute("file");
        configuration.removeRoute("dashboard");

        
        Notification.show("matched");

        if(role.equals(Role.USER)){
            configuration.setRoute("/ws",
                    ListView.class, MainLayout.class);
            configuration.setRoute("/file", FileUploadView.class, MainLayout.class);
        }
        else if(role.equals(Role.ADMIN)){
            configuration.setRoute("/file",
                    FileUploadView.class, AdminLayout.class);
            configuration.setRoute("/ws",
                    ListView.class, AdminLayout.class);
        }
    }

this is my authentication method. But When i click on the FileUploadView window after login has been successful I cannot access my user name using
VaadinSession session = VaadinSession.getCurrent(); if (session != null) { Userr user = session.getAttribute(Userr.class);}
the session is always returning null when i click on the fileUploadView.
Im very new to project building using java. Any kind of help is appreciated.
From a few searches I have been suggested that my FileUploadView is being instantiated before the authentication is completed. How to i fix this?
My expectation is that it will not return null, instead of the current user information

You shouldn't store the username yourself. Instead, you can access it from
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

The type of the object depends on your security implementation, but typically in simple cases it is UserDetails.
